# How can I prevent white flash before it loads my background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image, loading

> This is a for my portfolio...Any feedback would be appreciated. I have only been learning for about a week - but I do know basics of HTML and CSS up to only the flexbox, grid etc. I am yet to learn them. Currently using FCC and Youtube to learn...

Please see code below:

> This is a for my portfolio...Any feedback would be appreciated - such as wrong use of elements or such... The white background appears first before my background image. Is there a fix to it? TIA

```
html
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body{
    background-image:url(background.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;;

}
header{
    display: flex;
    height: 10vh;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left:80%;
    bottom: 0;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
    margin: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlinks{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.navlinks:hover{
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
    color:rgba(0, 247, 255, 0.473);
}
main{
    
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.introduction{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    /* background-color: white; */
    text-align: center;
    /* position: absolute; */

}
.introduction h2{
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.introduction h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span{
    color: #AEDCFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}
.introduction p{
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.aboutme-btn{
  
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 7rem;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0.3px black;
    background-color:transparent;
    cursor: pointer;

    

}
.aboutme-btn2{
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color:white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.692);
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
```

`CSS`

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body{
    background-image:url(background.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;;

}
header{
    display: flex;
    height: 10vh;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left:80%;
    bottom: 0;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
    margin: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlinks{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.navlinks:hover{
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
    color:rgba(0, 247, 255, 0.473);
}
main{
    
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.introduction{
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    /* background-color: white; */
    text-align: center;
    /* position: absolute; */

}
.introduction h2{
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.introduction h1{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span{
    color: #AEDCFF;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}
.introduction p{
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.aboutme-btn{
  
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 7rem;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0.3px black;
    background-color:transparent;
    cursor: pointer;

    

}
.aboutme-btn2{
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color:white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    
}
button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.692);
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please show us some code so we can see where your flashes appear.

Comment: Hi @Dreamchaser, Thanks for putting so much of css code here, Its bit difficult to find exact issue by looking so much of code in it. 
It would be helpful for us if you can use the code option from the editor and place your running code over there. Or please put your code somewhere and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to specify a background color that matches your background image more closely.